# Why <link> and not <style>?

Tags: html, syntax

Why do we type this:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/file.css' />
```

Instead of this:

```
<style type='text/css' src='/file.css' />
```

The reason that this seem unintuitive are that we use the `<style>` tag for inline CSS (just as we use the `<script>` tag for both inline and external Javascript).

Comment: So, you have just answered your own question...

Answer (score -1):

Of course you can use the  tag if you want, but that only works when your css code is embedded on the html file, in that case it will be like this:

```
<style media="screen" type="text/css">

Add style rules here

</style>
```

When you use the  tag you are "linking" an external resource to your current document, that's why we use the  "link" tag.

This is the definition from the W3:

> The  tag defines the relationship between a document and an
>   external resource.
>
> The  tag is most used to link to style sheets.

Comment: What's the difference between "linking" an external CSS file and external JavaScript file (which doesn't use `<link>`)?

Comment: The difference is that there is an specific tag for including client side scripts. Why is that, and why we don't use <link> to "link" a Javascript, wall that's a question that I cannot answer, the creators of HTML decided to make in that way.